# Suppose a and b are relatively prime and a,b,c are integers that $a^2+b^2=c^3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ are coprime gaussian integers and there are integers $m$ and $n$ such that $a = m^3 - 3mn^2$ and $b = 3m^2n - n^3$.

For this question, i just proved $a \not\equiv b$ and c is odd.

Answer (score 1):

"And there are integers $m$ and $n$ such that $a=m^3-3 m n^2$ and $b=3 m^2 n-n^3$"

Actually every $m$ and $n$ will work, by noticing that $(m^3-3 m n^2)^2+(3 m^2 n-n^3)^2 = (m^2+n^2)^3$

For the first statement of the question, also by substituting the same variables and GCD algorithm for Gaussian integers, you can arrive easily that the two numbers are **Coprimes**.

Comment: Very nice. $c=m^2+n^2$

Comment: @Zubin This follows much more conceptually from unique factorization - se my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an immediate consequence of the fact that Gaussian integers are a UFD. Then by unique factorization, with $\,w = a+bi,$ and $\,ww' = c^3$ and $w,w'$ coprime it follows that, up to unit factors, $w$ is a cube, so $\,w = (m+ni)^3 = m^3-3mn^2 + (3m^2n-n^3)i\,$ as claimed.

**Remark** $ $ This is the cubic analog of the well-known [derivation of the parametrization of Pythagorean triples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100486/242) using unique factorization of Gaussian integers. Follow the link for further discussion, including Weil's discussion of its relation with Fermat's method of *infinite descent*.